# Image doesn't display using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to `display` the contents from `database`. Following `query` is working fine, but the problem is `image` does not show anymore.

```
<?php
session_start();

// Include config file
require_once "../auth/dbconnection.php";

$output='';
    
$sql='select `image`,`title`,`sub_title`,`username`,`blog_id`,`body`,`published` from `blog` WHERE user_id=? ';

$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param( 's',$_SESSION['user_id'] );

$res=$stmt->execute();
if( $res ){
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($image,$title,$sub_title, $username, $blog_id,$body,$published);

      while( $stmt->fetch() ){
          
       $filepath="../assets/img/blog_images/";

        $title= substr($title,0,30);
        $body= substr($body,0,500);
             
        $date=   date('dS F Y', strtotime($published));
      
$output .=  '
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<div class="blog grid-blog">
<div class="blog-image">
<a href="#">';
$output .=  ' <img style="height:190px; width:330px;" class="img-fluid" src="data:image/png;base64, %s" alt="" />'; base64_encode(file_get_contents($filepath.$image) ) ;     
       
$output .=  ' </a>
</div>
<div class="blog-content">
<h3 class="blog-title"><a href="blog-details.html"> '.$title.' </a></h3>
<p>  <code>  '.$body.'  </code>  </p> <br>
<a href="blog-details.html" class="read-more"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Read More</a>
<div class="blog-info clearfix">
<div class="post-left">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#."><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span>'.$date.'</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="post-right"><a href="#."><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>21</a> <a href="#."><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>8</a> <a href="#."><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>17</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>';

}

echo $output;

    }else{

        echo 'No any post found';
    }     
?>
```

Can anyone guide me how can fix the issue, i would like to appreciate if someone guide me regarding this. Thank You.

Comment: why you put it on base64 encode? you can directly put the path url from src tag

Comment: Mostly I am using this method it working file, but the problem on working with `HTML`  contents this problem arises

Comment: I was going to say the same as @Jerson, and check your inspect elements in your browser to see what you get. Copy the base64 and check if the base64 is correct in an online tool

Comment: It shows `<img style="height:190px; width:330px;" class="img-fluid" src="data:image/png;base64, %s" alt="">`

Comment: If you can use the image always try to just use the image and not convert it into something else. Now every time the page gets loaded, your server needs to convert the image if you just use the original image, the image gets cached in the browser so tha page will load a bit faster

Comment: As per the suggestion given by @Jerson, it show like `<img style="height:190px; width:330px;" class="img-fluid" src="../assets/img/blog_images/1604470110.png" alt="">`

Comment: first check your image path then if it work, encode it, just put in src, its recommended to put directly, it can reduce request on server

Comment: The `database` only gets the `image` name with `.png` extention

Comment: The problem is `%s` You assign the image tag to $output and close it with `;` after that you do the base64. Replace `%s` with your base64_encode function. Now your server encodes the image but you do nothing with it

Comment: @Baracuda078 Thanks Mr. Baracuda078. It works well. I am very grateful for you. Thank you again for all who gave suggestions for me.

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: You're welcome maybe an other tip: If you write code like this (Mixing php and html) try to put the most php in the top of your file then close it with `?>` then you can write normal html if toy then need to echo something use `<?= $date; ?>` or for and `if` function `<?php if(): ?>` html content `<?php endif; ?>` I think that way your code gets better readable

Comment: Thanks Mr. @Baracuda078. #Stay safe

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you omit [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) function.
This should work.

```php
sprintf('<img src="data:image/png;base64, %s" alt="" />', base64_encode(file_get_contents($filepath.$image));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the image binary in separate variable to be easy to use

**$binary = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($filepath . $image));**

and use it like this

```
$output .= '<img style="height:190px; width:330px;" class="img-fluid" src="' . $binary . '" alt="" />';
```